# Autoconf macro to read define from header file and write to config.h

Tags: macros, autoconf

I am in the process of converting from a legacy build environment to one that uses the Autotools. I have a legacy header file that contains a large number of configuration values and that includes a number of other headers. I am trying to write a macro that can cherry pick specific defined values from the legacy configuration header and write them to `config.h`. I've been able to write the macro below that checks if the definition is equal to some value and perform some action. I would like to add a step that automatically writes the defined value to `config.h`.

```
AC_DEFUN([ZENO_CHECK_CONFIG],
    [
        AC_CHECK_HEADERS([legacy_config.h])
        AS_IF([test "x$ac_cv_header_legacy_config_h" = "xyes"],
            [
            AC_MSG_CHECKING([for definition of $1])
            AC_EGREP_CPP([test_true],
                [
#include <legacy_config.h>
#if defined($1) && $1 == $2
test_true
#endif
                ],
                [AC_MSG_RESULT([enabled])
                $3],
                [AC_MSG_RESULT([disabled])
                $4]
            )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [AC_DEFINE](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Symbols.html) or possibly AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED:

```
...
            [AC_MSG_RESULT([enabled])
             AC_DEFINE($1, $2)
            $3],
            [AC_MSG_RESULT([disabled])
             AC_DEFINE($1, something)
            $4]
...
```

Comment: That would work if the check was true however, I'd like to write the define regardless of the value.

Comment: So what happens when the check is false?

Comment: I'd like the write the actual defined value from the legacy configuration header to `config.h` regardless of the check. Effectively just "copy" it from the legacy configuration header to `config.h`.

Comment: [autoheader](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#autoheader-Invocation) might be useful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
dnl -------------------------------------------------------------------  
dnl check if libmqmsgque.la was build with libconfig
                                                                        
dnl # 1. add include directory
CPPFLAGS="-I$abs_builddir/../../.. $CPPFLAGS"

AC_MSG_CHECKING([for NHI1 'HAVE_LIBCONFIG' in 'msgque_config.h'])

dnl # 2. compile and run small program with failure on not found
AC_RUN_IFELSE([
  AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include "msgque_config.h"], [                                                                               
    #ifdef HAVE_LIBCONFIG  
      return 0;  
    #else
      return 1;                                                                                                                 
    #endif  
  ])   
],[    
  AC_MSG_RESULT([found])
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LIBCONFIG,[1],[libmqmsgque was build with libconfig])  
],[
  AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])  
])
```